# Unable to add maven dependency

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

When i right click on project then Maven then Add Dependencies.
It is showing error. Artifact id cannot be empty.
I had rebuild index.
I don't know what to put in artifact id and group id.
I want to add Hibernate libraries.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse w/ m2e plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `pom.xml` in the section `dependencies`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

From the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html):

> The minimum requirement for a POM are the following:
>
> - project root
> - modelVersion - should be set to 4.0.0
> - groupId - the id of the project's group.
> - artifactId - the id of the artifact (project)
> - version - the version of the artifact under the specified group